# ReferenceError: Cannot access 'product' before initialization

Tags: node.js, express, postman, mern

I got stuck on some error in this code every time I try to get or post it gives an error at either at const product = await product.find(); or   const product = await product.create(req.body);
help me out with this

const { findById } = require('../models/product')
const product = require('../models/product')

// create new product  => /api/v1/product/new
exports.newProduct = async(req,res,next) => {

```
const product = await product.create(req.body);

res.status(201).json({
    success: true,
    product:"Hello"
})
```

}

// get all products => /api/v1/products
exports.getProducts = async(req,res,next) => {

```
const product = await product.find();

res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    count: product.length,
    products
})
```

}

//  Get single product details => /api/v1/product/:id

exports.getsingleProduct = async(req,res,next) => {
const product = await product.findById(req.params.id);

```
if(!product){
    return res.status(404).json({
    success: false,
    message: 'product not found'
})

}

res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    product

})
```

}

Comment: I think you should use another variable name when referencing product class, btw you also need to add code on how did you import that product class.